# Python - Invalid Syntax - Driver_find_element_by_xpath

Tags: html, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to capture all elements of a web page using `Selenium` web driver `XPATH`. All of the rows I am trying to capture start with the same text. Therefore, I used the code below:

```
container = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(//*[starts-with(@id,"revalgridview-3806")])
```

I keep getting an `"invalid syntax error"` in Jupyter.

I can't figure out where I am going wrong.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

From what you currently have above it looks like you are missing quotes in `driver.find_elements_by_xpath(` call. Therefore, it is interpreting it as a comment and never finding the ending parenthesis.

Therefore, it should be something like: `container = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[starts-with(@id,"revalgridview-3806")]')`

Comment: This should nail the OP